# Need help on implementing LZW on a ASCII text file

Tags: php, algorithm, lzw

i'm trying to implement an LZW to compress an ASCII based text file and i need help.

Let's say i have a text file with a "BABAABAAAA" written on it, and i use my code to compress it using LZW algorithm. The output of the result will be written on a text file, which results

```
66|65|256|257|65|260|65
```

Now the problem is, the compressed file would have a bigger size than the original file because it counts each char of the codes as a single char rather than counting each code as a single integer. So instead of reading 65 as 01000001 instead it thinks of 65 as 2 ascii char which is 00110110 (6) 00110101 (5). And that's not even counting the marker ('|').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you convert some text into series of integers, like `66|65|256`, you should not write it to a file as a series of 9 characters in text mode. You should open the output file in binary mode and write the numbers in binary (and not write seperation marks like `|` at all).

In case of LZW there are two approaches: either you use fixed binary width, and thus limit the size of dictionary, or implement (a little bit harder) variable width version, in which each number uses as many binary digits as the NEXT free dictionary key.

Back to your example, `66|65|256|257|65|260|65` with fixed width of 9 bits gives you `7 * 9 = 63` bits, which is `8` bytes.

Comment: Umm how do i write it as a binary file using PHP?

Comment: Actually PHP is a weird choice for that algorithm. The naive way would be to first convert series of integers into series of boolean values (the bit representation), then you could split it into bytes by 8 and write to `fopen($path, 'wb')`.

Comment: Are you saying to convert them into a binary first?
65 = 01000001
What i don't get is how to write 01000001 as binary file, and read it. Sorry i never handled a binary file before, i'm still a newbie on this

Comment: may i have an example of binary file? @Batsosz

Comment: Every file is a binary file. Binary is not a kind of file but a way to look at a file. Every file is a sequence of bits. Binary mode means only that you do not want to interpret the bytes as characters of some encoding, but rather numbers (from `00` to `FF` in hexadecimal).